# How to deal with template const and non-const parameters?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a Template function taking in const types such as:

```
template <class T, class U>
    void process(const T& v1, const U& v2)
    {
      //do some things
      verify(v1);
      verify(v2);
    }
```

Then the verify function checks the Type for T using if constexpr as follows:
(The function also returns the variable. I set it to auto for the purpose of this question)

```
template <class T>
    auto verify(const T& t)
    {
      if constexpr (is_same_v<T, int>)
          return t;
      if constexpr (is_same_v<T, string>)
          return t;
      if constexpr (is_same_v<T, double*>)
          return t;
      else
          static_assert(false, "Type not allowed");
    }
```

if the type is not found it will trigger a compilation error.
This all works very fine but the problem is I would like to make v2 a non-const U& parameter. This triggers the static_assert and I don't know why. I also set all parameters in both functions to non-const but I still get the same error. All I really want is to pass the arguments by reference. Can anyone give me some hints? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There seem to be some issues with the shown code, that are not relevant to the problem. e.g. `variant` could simply be made auto for the purpose of this question. Importantly, what is the parameter `U` in `verify`? You don't seem to be using it at all.

Comment: Thanks, it was a typo. I updated my question.

Comment: process is lacking a `return`

Comment: You also can't say `static_assert(false)` like that, you'll need to do an indirection with [dependent_false<T>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if).

Comment: Template type deduction (including const and other things) is complicated.  I think the link is [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction)

Comment: process has no return type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of those things you'd need to know.

The form you're looking for is

```
template <class T> auto verify(T&& t) {
```

The reason is that `T` can be `const U`, a const-qualified type. The double `&&` is necessary for rvalue references.

You probably want `std::is_same_v<std::remove_cv_t<T>>, ...`

And to simply things:

```
template <class T> auto verify(T&& t)
{
  using baseT = std::remove_cv_t<T>;
  static_assert(is_same_v<baseT, int> || 
                is_same_v<baseT, string> ||
                is_same_v<baseT, double*>);
  return t;
}
```

Comment: This worked after using using baseT = remove_cv_t<remove_reference_t<T>>; (or if you are using c++20 remove_cvref_t). Thanks btw

Answer (score 1):

A better way of doing that would be to `static_assert` some type trait:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

template <class T, class... Y>
inline bool constexpr is_one_of =
    (std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>, std::decay_t<Y>> || ...);

template <class T>
void verify() {
  static_assert(is_one_of<T, int, std::string, double*>);
}

template <class T, class U>
void process(T const& v1, U const& v2) {
  verify<T>();
  verify<U>();

  // ...
}
```